# Raspberry Pi: ACL on ramfs?

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, sudo, acl, sudoers

I am build custom image for Raspberry Pi 4 using Yocto. I trying to create user group account with privilages set using ACL. When rootfs is present on SD card everything works, but when I rootfs resides in RAM (fitImage) ACL seems to not working... I'm wondering what is a difference?
The CONFIG_TMPFS_POSIX_ACL in kernel config is set to y.

Bellow my initramfs recipe:

```
require recipes-core/images/super-pi.bb

IMAGE_NAME = "super-pi-initramfs"
IMAGE_FSTYPES := "${INITRAMFS_FSTYPES}"
IMAGE_FSTYPES:remove = " wic wic.gz"

PACKAGE_INSTALL:append = " ${IMAGE_INSTALL}"

IMAGE_NAME_SUFFIX ?= ""
IMAGE_LINGUAS = ""
IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE = "0"

DEPENDS:append = " acl-native"


inherit extrausers


#to generate hash for password: printf "%q" $(mkpasswd -m sha256crypt 
<password>)
#pass: puma1
DEVELOPER_PASSWORD_HASH = 
 "\$5\$5j7bye3XKroIht0\$rZ3af/o3gVXLYo5vqtfbjllCSa5jtx2QrRraKaWwqn5"
#pass: puma2
PRODUCTION_PASSWORD_HASH = 
"\$5\$uoMhBHIwh8ReIv1\$Fxuh8QN4my0pNfOe/RGfLhMGD5LxVk6UOWupprvgFT/"
#pass: puma3
SERVIS_PASSWORD_HASH = 
"\$5\$Q.5Zmboz3pIJ3hT\$Xi0f6YTzYGvTjD3cnniNa6htyBB/cY5GT7eUUM1Puq4"
#pass: puma4
VISITOR_PASSWORD_HASH = 
"\$5\$7CBZsfthWke7GmAw\$uuejwFB.BuAyFAeTY7b40qXxg4oA4G8e7X/hztSIsh0"

EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "\
    groupadd --gid 1001 developer; \
    groupadd --gid 1002 production; \
    groupadd --gid 1003 servis; \
    groupadd --gid 1004 visitor; \
    useradd --uid 1011 --no-user-group --no-create-home --password 
   '${DEVELOPER_PASSWORD_HASH}' --shell /bin/bash developer; \
    useradd --uid 1012 --no-user-group --no-create-home --password 
   '${PRODUCTION_PASSWORD_HASH}' --shell /bin/bash production; \
    useradd --uid 1013 --no-user-group --no-create-home --password 
   '${SERVIS_PASSWORD_HASH}' --shell /bin/bash servis; \
   useradd --uid 1014 --no-user-group --create-home --password 
   '${VISITOR_PASSWORD_HASH}' --shell /bin/bash visitor; \
   usermod -g developer developer; \
   usermod -g production production; \
   usermod -g servis servis; \
   usermod -g visitor visitor; \
"

modify_user_access() {

    setfacl -R -m g:developer:rwX ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc  \
                   ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/usr  \
                   ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/lib  \
                   ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/bin  \
                   ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/sbin \
                   ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/sys  \
                   ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/boot \
                   ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/proc \
                   ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/media \
                   ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/mnt \
                   ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/var \
                   ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/run;
    bbnote "setfacl result: $?"

    setfacl -R -m g:production:rwX ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc \
                ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/usr \
                ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/lib \
                ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/bin \
                ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/sbin \
                ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/media \
                    ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/mnt;                    

        bbnote "setfacl result: $?"             
        setfacl -R -m g:servis:rX ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc \
                ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/usr \
                ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/bin \
                ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/sbin \
                ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/media \
                    ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/mnt;
         bbnote "setfacl result: $?"                    
         setfacl -R -m g:visitor:--- ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/;              
         setfacl -R -m g:visitor:r ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/home/visitor;
         bbnote "setfacl result: $?"                
  }


  modify_sudoers() {
         sed -i.bak 's/# Cmnd_Alias\tREBOOT/Cmnd_Alias\tREBOOT/' 
         ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/sudoers
         sed -i.bak 's/# Cmnd_Alias\tPROCESSES/Cmnd_Alias\tPROCESSES/' 
         ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/sudoers
         sed -i.bak 's/# \t\t\t    \/usr\/bin\/pkill/ \t\t\t    
          \/usr\/bin\/pkill/' ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/sudoers
         
         echo "%developer ALL=(ALL) REBOOT, PROCESSES, /usr/bin/setfacl" >  
         ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/sudoers.d/0001_custom_sudo_rules
         echo "%production ALL=(ALL) REBOOT, PROCESSES, /usr/bin/setfacl" 
         >> ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/sudoers.d/0001_custom_sudo_rules
    
         rm ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/sudoers.bak
     }


     rootfs_update_timestamp() {
         date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S" > ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/timestamp
     }

   IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND += "modify_user_access;"
   ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "rootfs_update_timestamp;modify_sudoers;"
```